# Choose blackberry 10 platform to use call logs, messages, data usage all this functionality through application

Tags: blackberry-10

Please help me to choose correct blackberry 10 platform to create application which will access call logs,sms,data usage records from the mobile. Blackberry 10 webworks and Android runtime doesn't support all API's required for this application. Now I am planning to switch to native development. In native application should I go for core development or cascades development?

Comment: What does your research tell you?

Answer (score 0):

The difference between using Cascades or not is simple: in both cases, you develop a native application. Cascades simply offers you a richer API. Everything you can do with Cascades, you can also do it without, Cascades is just simplifying a ton of things. For example, without using Cascades, you'll have to create your own, complete GUI system. With Cascades, you have already one, which is integrated and homogeneous with the system.

Usually, when developing a native application, not using Cascades is reserved to a particular type of applications: games, which creates their own GUI. For a "standard" (read: not a game) application, you really should use Cascades.